# Timelike curves

Tags: riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

I can't find clear definitions of what it means for a curve to be timelike or null except for those on wikipedia. Can anyone reference some literature?

Comment: What is the definition you have problems understanding (and what is it that is not clear with it)?

Comment: And what is your background? It would be silly to point you to a text you can't understand yet.

Comment: The definition I have is that a timelike curve is a curve such that the tangent vector at each point along the curve is timelike. Where a tangent vector is timelike if $g(X,X)<0$. The problem I am having is I can't find this definition anywhere except for Wikipedia and that is why I am reluctant to accept it.

Comment: I am studying for a masters degree in mathematics. Have experience with Riemannian Geometry.

Comment: Well that is the correct definition. You can find it in any introduction text on general relativity: $X$ is timelike if $g(X,X) <0$, null if $g(X,X) = 0$ and spacelike if $g(X,X) > 0$. For an explicit reference see for example page 4 of https://preposterousuniverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/grtinypdf.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent reference to anything related to both relativity and Riemannian geometry is of course "Semi-Riemannian Geometry With Applications to Relativity" by Barret O'Neill.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome!